# C# Invoke Method Console Write Demo

Tags: c#

The code snippet below is from an ASP.NET MVC application. It accepts all parameters from browser. I believe it's vulnerable.

I'm testing an application's security, it uses Invoke method, but accepts the Object type, method and parameters dynamically from user's input. I believe it is dangerous and I'm trying to prove it.

Do you think I can invoke Console.Write or execute some sort of arbitrary/dangerous code?

I want to try to use C# Invoke Method to write to console to prove the vulnerability. This is what I did:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type magicType = Type.GetType("System");
    ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });                

    MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("Console.Write");
    object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[] { 100 });
}
```

But it doesn't work. It says Object is not initialized. What am I missing?

Comment: Anyone care to comment why downvotes? 2 downvotes just for a question? Maybe I shouldn't ask any questions here

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with the `asp.net-mvc` tag?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, That's a perfect reason for downvote! Yaaay!

Comment: How can I delete my question? Seems like no one liked it

Comment: @JohnMcKean you asked your question just under ten minutes ago. I think your question is unclear (what are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you just use `Console.Write`?), which is probably why it has a couple of downvotes. Tagging is important on SO, but not a reason people usually down-vote questions.

Comment: @JohnMcKean I actually didn't downvote your question, and even answered it. I was just wondering if that tag is necessary.

Comment: I removed the bad tag, I know Console.Write, I'm trying to figure out Invoke method and I will be using it for some other purpose (security testing of an app)

Comment: Updated the question with more explanation on why I want to do it this way. The reason I had ASP.NET tag was, because it was an ASP.NET application

Comment: @JohnMcKean I've augmented your question based on your comments. Please clean it up if it's nonsensical or not what you're actually asking. You should also specify where the code lives (in a controller, presumably?) in the question text.

Comment: @ashes999, perfectly done! This is exactly my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System` is not a *type*, it's a *namespace*. You're actually looking for `System.Console`, which is the console class. After that, you're looking for the `WriteLine` method with the proper overload, which takes an `int`, which is what you pass to `Type.GetMethod`. Only then, you can invoke the `MethodInfo` object using `Invoke` passing `null` as the object (as this is a `static` class) and the right parameter.

What you actually want is this:

```
Type magicType = Type.GetType("System.Console");
var method = magicType.GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(int) });
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 100 });
```

Comment: Why would someone do this over invoking `System.Console.WriteLine` directly?

Comment: I'm testing an application's security, it uses Invoke method, but accepts the Object type, method and parameters dynamically from user's input. I believe it is dangerous and I'm trying to prove it

Comment: @JohnMcKean Your question completely valid. Even if this isn't a "conventional" way of invoking a method, no reason not to ask about it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, So the code snipped I posted is from a web application. It accepts all parameters from browser. I believe it's vulnerable. Do you think I can invoke Console.Write or something like that using the code I posted. You code doesn't have second and third line.

Comment: @JohnMcKean I believe you should have stated this in your question itself -- that you want to know if it is vulnerable if a web app runs code like this.

Comment: Generally, invoking methods based on parameters passed by a web request sounds like a terrible idea. You don't need all that code that you posted, you can use the snippet I provided.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thanks for all the explanations. The code is already written like that and I'm testing it. I saw that snipped and I think it's terrible, but I have to provide a PoC (proof-of-concept), for example invoking Console.Write. Can we do that in the code I posted as-is just by replacing strings part which is in control of user?

Comment: It always crashes at third line with error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I do Console.Write

Comment: Where are you calling `Console.Write`?